# C# Xml why doesn't my attribute appears?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xml-attribute

I have a class defined like this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="request")]
public class Request
{
    #region Attributes
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "version")]
    public string Version
    {
        get
        {
            return "1.0";
        }
    }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "action")]
    public EAction Action
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion
```

But when I serialize it, "version" doesn't show up in the attribute (while "action" does).

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` is going to ignore `Version` because it doesn't have a `set`, so there is no way it can attempt to ever *deserialize* it. Perhaps instead:

```
[XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "version")]
public string Version {get;set;}

public Request() { Version = "1.0"; }
```

which will have the same effect overall (although will require an extra `string` field per-instance - although all of the `"1.0"` values will be the same actual `string` instance, via *interning*), but will allow you to capture properly the version of data you are *deserializing*.

If you *don't care* about deserialization, then maybe just add a no-op `set`:

```
[XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "version")]
public string Version
{
    get { return "1.0"; }
    set { }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set an empty setter. It's a limitation of XmlAttribute.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="request")]
public class Request
{
    #region Attributes
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "version")]
    public string Version
    {
        get
        {
            return "1.0";
        }
        set{}
    }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "action")]
    public EAction Action
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion
```